# Create web parts for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I saw 2 different way to create web parts for sharepoint. Which one is preferred by most?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973249%28office.12%29.aspx

Comment: I guess I left out the 2nd way.        http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/developing-sharepoint-2007-web-parts?page=0,4
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817.aspx

Comment: Both SharepointOverflow and Stackoverflow aren't much help. Used to be really good. I followed this link and I guess I am happy with the result. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Anything involving VSeWSS is just going to end in pain, so method 1 is definitely out. Method 2 isn't ideal either, as setting up html elements as controls becomes unmanageable at a level just beyond what you see in that demo. I use a fairly simple generic base class that takes a user control as a type parameter and lets me keep all the layout nicely seperated from the sharepoint infrastructure. If you are creating pages/web parts programatically most of the web part xml turns out to be optional also.

```
public abstract class UserControlWebPart<T> : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart where T:UserControl
{
    protected UserControlWebPart()
    {
        this.ExportMode = WebPartExportMode.All;
    }

    protected virtual void TransferProperties(T ctrl)
    {
        var tc = typeof(T);
        var tt = this.GetType();

        foreach (var p in tt.GetProperties()) {
            if (p.IsDefined(typeof(ControlPropertyAttribute), true)) {
                foreach (var p2 in tc.GetProperties()) {
                    if (p2.Name == p.Name) {
                        p2.SetValue(ctrl, p.GetValue(this, null), null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }


    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        string controlURL = ControlFolder+typeof(T).Name+".ascx";
        var ctrl = Page.LoadControl(controlURL) as T;
        TransferProperties(ctrl);
        this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }

    protected virtual string ControlFolder
    {
        get {
            return "~/_layouts/UserControlWebParts/";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This looks better and I truly appreciate the inside story of each uses. Great Job. Again. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

For the few web parts I've written, I guess I've gone more with method #2 than method #1.  Seems more straightforward and has the potential to be reused outside of the SharePoint environment (depending on the depth of your business logic).

Comment: Thanks Jesse for your input. I know what you mean about using the second method. Web part are based on asp.net (2.0), therefore it's more useful beyond sharepoint application. Thanks for your words.